# Multiple-selection List Box filtering by 2 Drop-Down lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

In my InfoPath 2010 form (which is also published in SharePoint 2010 site) I have 2 drop-down lists: "Delivery type" and "Primary technology". Under "delivery type", let's say, I have options: A, B, C, D, E; under primary technology I have options: Java, Oracle, SAP. By choosing Java and A from both drop-downs user should see one set of values in the multiple selection list box, by choosing, for example, SAP + C, user should see another set of values in the multiple selection list box.

Is it even possible to filter the values of multiple-selection list box based on the values from two drop-down lists? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a "matching" list of sorts. What it sounds like you may have done is created a list for Delivery Type and a List for Primary Technology. In a third list add three fields Delivery Type;Primary Technology;Multi-select ID.  In a forth list that has your Multi-Select options.

In the info path rules, set the field value in the query properties of the third list whenever the Delivery and technology drop downs change.

On the third list set a rule to query the Multi-Select ID with those from the third list. I hope that is all clear.

Your multi-select field values will be limited by the third list and its info path query.